# pullRefresh spinner does not stop

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation, however, when I get an error, then my `pullRefresh` animation still spinning until I do `pullRefresh` again. I wonder what I am doing wrong?

note - `dataCollectionView` is added on the `UIViewController`.

```
func setupPullRefresh() {
    pullRefresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    dataCollectionView.addSubview(pullRefresh)
}

@objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    callData()
}

private func callData() {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    
    classVM.fetchData() { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error == nil {
                self.dataCollectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                self.showAlert(message: error?.localizedDescription, title: "Error")
            }
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            pullRefresh.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.pullRefresh.endRefreshing()
```

It will call when "classiVM.fetchData ()" completed. It will probably take a few seconds. You had "activityIndicator". You can leave it like this.

```
private func callData() {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    pullRefresh.endRefreshing()

    classVM.fetchData() { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error == nil {
                self.dataCollectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                self.showAlert(message: error?.localizedDescription, title: "Error")
            }
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason the spinner might not stop spinning is if the behavior has accidentally been set to "Animating" in the inspection window. In my case I couldn't figure out why "spinner.stopAnimating" code was not working until the box was unchecked.
[image: Spinner Attribute Inspector]